# PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED - On DocuSign POST envelope

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am trying to send an envelope request using this [tutorial](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email?utm_campaign=DevCenter%20Nurture%20-%20Sandbox%20Email%202&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua).  I am using NodeJS trying to hard code the PDFFile in base64Format but I am getting the PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED.
This is my code:

```
options.multipart = [{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data",
        "body": JSON.stringify(body),
    }, {
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
        'Content-Disposition': 'file; filename="' + documentName + '"; documentId=1',
        "body": "data:application/pdf;base64,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"
    }
    ];
```

I am following this exact example except for the body in the multipart in which I've substituted fs.readFileSync(documentName) by this:

```
"data:application/pdf;base64,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"
```

there is any conversion/encryption in the file I am missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also specify `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

```
options.multipart = [
    {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data",
        "body": JSON.stringify(body),
    },
    {
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
        'Content-Disposition': 'file;filename="' + documentName + '"; documentId=1',
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "base64",
        "body": "<Base64 Bytes here>"
    }
];
```

Also `data:application/pdf;base64` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together a multi-part mime message is a bother. But one of the advantages is that the format supports binary. Ie, you *don't* have to Base64 encode it.

I'd try **without** the Base64 encoding.

(As is shown in the recipe.)